# Add nodes in telerik treeview

Tags: telerik, treeview, radtreeview

i need to add treenode type nodes in radtreeview but this won't work, help required

```
TreeNode result = new TreeNode(path);
this.radTreeView1.Nodes.Add(result);
```

i need to give treenode type argument whereas it accepts string type while same works fine for  simple treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to Add Tree Node to RadTreeView it has to be of type RadTreeNode and yes it also accpets string as Text and also it has another constructor that accepts Text and value and below:

```
RadTreeNode result=new RadTreeNode(path);// that would be the Text of the Node
```

or//

`RadTreeNode result=new RadTreeNode(path,"value");`// this constructor accepts first argument and the Node text and the second as the Node value

regards